# Read Serial Port in Windows CE using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read from serial port using python 2.5 in windows CE 5.0.
What is happening is It gets connected to serial port but nothing gets read from the port.
Below is my Code

```
import ceserial
from time import sleep

ser = ceserial.Serial(port="COM1:",baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,stopbits=ceserial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=ceserial.PARITY_EVEN,
                      timeout=0)
ser.open()
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
while True:
    data = ser.read(size=50)
    if len(data) > 0:
        print 'Got:', data
    sleep(0.5)
ser.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing gets read"? The line `data = ser.read(size=50)` will block if there are less than 50 bytes available. Try reading fewer bytes or checking how many are available by using `ser.inWaiting()`.

Comment: It shows connected to: COM5 thats it. data = ser.read(size=50)
n = ser.inWaiting() still the same reads nothing

Comment: n = ser.inWaiting()
if n:
  data = data + ser.read(n) print data this is how i have tried